# GUI drag & drop style GUI Builder for Python Tkinter

Tags: windows, open-source, software-development, python, gui-builder

I'm looking for a GUI drag-and-drop style GUI builder for Python Tkinter where I can create windows with forms, buttons, labels, etc. without actually writing any code.

I would like the software to meet these requirements:

- Open source where I can use the software for commercial projects
- Compatible with Windows 10 64-bit
- Uses latest Python (v3) & Tkinter standards, and is an active project

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One tool that I've been using is called Pygubu. It's open source and can be run anywhere python is installed. It includes support for not only Python version 3 but also version 2 as well. It appears to be an active and popular project and includes documentation too.

## [Pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu) ([open source](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu))

> `Pygubu` is a [RAD tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) to enable *quick* and *easy development of user interfaces* for the Python's `tkinter` module.
>
> The user interfaces designed are saved as [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files, and, by using the *pygubu builder*, these can be loaded by applications dynamically as needed.
>
> Pygubu is inspired by [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org).
>
> [image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Unfortunately, it only works with Python 2, which is past its end-of-life.

Comment: @TheDaleks It also supports Python 3. Although `Python >= 2.7` is certainly not the best way to indicate Python 3 support.

Comment: just to mention - there is a web version (at first I skept this answer cause I haven't found it in my linux distro software center)

Comment: @OhadCohen a web version? Didn't found on Google. Can you please share the link? Thanks! 

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this simple to use website

[visualtk.com](https://visualtk.com/)

Where you can create input fields,labels,buttons,checkboxes,radiobox,listbox and messages of your application by drag and drop.You can also customize any of them to the color and look you want.
After that, you can download the complete python code of the visual.

[image]

Comment: Link only answers aren't very helpful. If you could summarize the features or limitations it would make the answer better.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Mind to elaborate how that meets the requirements? Especially "open source" (versus "all rights reserved"), "create windows with forms, buttons, labels, etc. without actually writing any code", "latest standards", "active project"? As it is put now, it's rather a comment than an answer – so please **[edit]** your post to include the facts. Thanks!

Comment: this site seems to be partially in asian. context menu to edit a widget has menu items I can't decipher from the asian script. further, site supports an incredibly limited list of widgets. doesn't even have a progressbar.

Answer (score 5):

Use " **PAGE** ":

http://page.sourceforge.net

> PAGE is an drag-and-drop GUI generator, bearing a resemblance to Visual Basic. It allows one to easily create GUI windows containing a selection of Tk and ttk widgets.

Use it to build GUIs in Python and Tcl/tk.  But before you install it you must download **Activestate Tcl/tk** software.

It really speeds up the design activity. Also learn how to code in Tkinter to make cosmetic changes. I recommend BUCKY's tutorials on YouTube on tkinter.

Comment: it has too many bugs, too many floating windows, I couldn't figure it out, and returned to pyGUBU

Answer (score 3):

For creating "windows with forms, buttons, labels, etc" as you say, sounds like this may meet your needs:

[www.python-gui-builder.com](http://www.python-gui-builder.com)

It's not super complex, but can certainly make buttons, labels, progress bars, and other things.  It lets you create Python 3 Tkinter GUIs right in your browser, and displays the Python code in a column on the right-hand side.  All you need is to then copy-paste the code into Python.

It requires no download or installation, and is open-source.  I'd recommend it for simple GUIs for Python.

Comment: This is great and its creating simple non-oop Code

Comment: terrible usability. I doubt it's even maintained.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I agree its kind of ironic that a website that is meant to build GUIs on has a bad GUI itself. But it is last updated on 2020

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in colourful and creative applications, then I'd recommend using **PAGE** and **Tkinter**. **PAGE** takes care of all the backend coding and gives you a clean file to write custom code but you need to learn **TKINTER** to build applications.

**GTK builder** is also an option. It's easy to code but *UI* is dull.